# ESS : Seeing vignettes for a package without attaching the corresponding package

Tags: ess, r

Suppose I wish to see the vignettes for an R package via ESS. I can do it like this:-

```
# This in the R process
library(car)
# This in the minibuffer
M-x ess-display-vignettes
```

My question is this: Can I see the vignettes in a package *without* attaching it to the namespace via the library incantation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a prefix argument (`C-u`), `ess-display-vignettes` will show vignettes from all installed packages.

From the help for this function (`C-h f ess-display-vignettes`):

> ess-display-vignettes is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> ‘ess-help.el’.
>
> (ess-display-vignettes &optional ALL)
>
> Display vignettes if available for the current dialect.
> With (prefix) ALL non-nil, use ‘vignette(*, all=TRUE)‘, i.e., from all installed
> packages, which can be *very* slow.

So do `C-u M-x ess-display-vignettes` (and maybe wait a few seconds if you have a lot of installed packages).